# List<> does not contain the definiton for getAwaiter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

I  am implementing automapper in my asp.net webapi project. I have also implemented async tasks in the business layer.  I basically want to return MoviesDto object instead of Movie entity but getting an error List does not contain the definiton for getAwaiter.The error is at the line

```
return await _mapper.Map<List<MoviesDto>>(movies);
```

Not sure what the problem is. Here is my code below

**MoviesDto**

```
public class MoviesDto : BaseDto
    {
        public int MovieID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int? ReleaseYear { get; set; }
        public string Plot { get; set; }
        public int? MovieLength { get; set; }
    }
```

**Business Access Layer**

```
public class MovieBusiness: IMovieBusiness
    {
        IMovieService _movieService;
        IMapper _mapper;

        public MovieBusiness(IMovieService movieService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _movieService = movieService;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<MoviesDto>> GetAllMovies()
        {

            var movies = _movieService.GetMovies();
            return await _mapper.Map<List<MoviesDto>>(movies);
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is no point in marking the `Map()` method as `async` as it doesn't involve I/O and cannot potentially block. It's `_movieService.GetMovies()` that better be `async` and should be `await`ed.

Answer (score 0):

The method `_mapper.Map()` is not async, so you don't have to `await` it.

Just use `return _mapper.Map<List<MoviesDto>>(movies);`

Comment: It won't compile as the method signature is bound to return `Task<IEnumerable<MoviesDto>>`

Comment: So do you mean I cant use automapper with asyn methods

Comment: @Tom you can. Just return `_mapper.Map` (it will be compiled) or use `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: Sorry didnt get you. If I return only _Mapper.Map it doesnt work as it the method is of the type async and expects await. Can you give me an example of Task.FromResult